# how to get dictionary to javascript and use it to change checkboxes value?

Tags: django, django-models

i want to cahnge my checkboxes to being checked using dicitonary.i am unable to get the dictionary to javascript too
this is my models.py

```
# Create your models here.
class Logs(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    checkbox_dict = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=dict)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def get_special_combination_value(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self.name,self.password)
```

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import Logs
from .forms import Login
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login ,logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse
# Create your views here.
def loger(request):
    formy = AuthenticationForm()
    c=[]
    a=Logs.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formy = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        name=request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        obj=Logs()
        obj.get_special_combination_value
        for b in a:
            if name == b.name and password == b.password:
                return redirect('ticket',pk=b.id)
    return render(request,'project/loger.html',{'formy':formy,'a':a})
def homepage(request):
    form=Login()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=Login(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save()
            return redirect('ticket',pk=user.pk)
    return render(request,'project/homepage.html',{'form':form})

def ticket(request,pk):
    tic=Logs.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request,'project/ticket.html',{'tic':tic})
def forgor(request):
    a=Logs.objects.all()
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('name')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        obj=Logs()
        obj.get_special_combination_value
        Logs.objects.filter(name=username).update(password=password)
        return redirect('homepage')
    return render(request,'project/forgor.html',{'a':a})
def plane(request,pk):
    log_instance = Logs.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        checkbox_dict_json = request.POST.get('checkboxDict')
        if checkbox_dict_json:
            # Parse the JSON data from the request
            checkbox_dict = json.loads(checkbox_dict_json)
            
            # Update the 'json_data' field of the instance with the new JSON data
            log_instance.json_data = checkbox_dict
            Logs.objects.update(checkbox_dict=checkbox_dict)
    
    # Retrieve the JSON data from the instance
    checkbox = log_instance.checkbox_dict
    print(checkbox)

    return render(request, 'project/plane.html', {'checkbox':checkbox})
```

this is my plane.html(shortened version)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .a, .b {
                transform: scale(2.5);
            }

            .b {
                margin-left: 200px; /* Add margin between the two divs */
            }

            /* Additional CSS to adjust the layout */
            .a, .b {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #sub
            {
                margin-bottom: -200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="a">
                    <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="seat">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
```

this is my javascript

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var checkboxDict = {};
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        checkboxDict[checkbox.id] = checkbox.checked;
    });

    // Set the value of the hidden input to the JSON representation of checkboxDict
    document.querySelector('#checkboxDict').value = JSON.stringify(checkboxDict);

    // Now submit the form
    this.submit();
});
});
let dic= {% autoescape off %}{{checkbox}}{% endautoescape %};
for(const[i,j] of Object.entries(dic))
{
console.log(i,j)
}
</script>
```

i am facing problem in getting the dictionary to my javascript and changing the checkboxes to being ticked

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox is just a boolean field:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield

When you build your view and form for this, simply reference the boolean field from the model. This will show up by default as a checkbox. If you want anything other than a checkbox (eg an on/off slider) you override the widget.

In your case though, I suspect you don't want a boolean field on your model. You want a seat number.

Your view then takes the seat number and decides which checkbox on the template should be checked, and when the form is POSTed, the view does the reverse - checks which seat is checked and transforms it into a seat number to store in the database.

Edit after comment:

Each checkbox needs to be in the form you are submitting so you can interrogte the data in the view. So then you can iterate over the various checkbox fields and when you find the one that is checked you can set the seat number.

You'll need to assign a unique ID to each seat checkbox to do this, so you know what seat each is actually referring to.

Comment: Exactly. But I don't get how I would get the id with its value.

Comment: i added id in all the input tags but i am facing trouble iterating over the checkbox field could you help me with that